# how to use kotlin data class and springboot-Validation to verify Null type at the same time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, validation

```kotlin
data class GetSourceListRequest(   
    @NotNull(message = "category not allow null")
    val category: List<Int>    
)
```

Then use `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions.

```kotlin
@ExceptionHandler(value = [HttpMessageNotReadableException::class])
    fun <T> httpMessageNotReadableExceptionHandler(e: HttpMessageNotReadableException): String {          
        return e.message
    }
```

The error message obtained is as follows:

> JSON parse error: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.sage.feature.source.database.request.GetSourceListRequest] value failed for JSON property category due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter category which is a non-nullable type

**But it's not what I expected, `@NotNull` didn't work because the json conversion had an error before that.**

I found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896933/kotlin-data-class-and-bean-validation-notnull-on-long-fields-does-not-work), but the solution it gives is to make the property a nullable type, which is not the perfect solution.

How to use springboot-validation in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried making the category field nullable?:

```
data class GetSourceListRequest(   
    @NotNull(message = "category not allow null")
    val category: List<Int>?
)
```

I know this functionally changes your Request object but this is the general  problem I have found when you want to use later-firing validation - the "carrier" object needs to allow for nulls.

The problem goes further with `enum` values where you cannot necessarily get a good error message if the type only permits valid enum values.

An alternate suggestion for you is to consider a Kotlin-native validation framework that works alongside Spring : [Konform](https://github.com/konform-kt/konform/tree/master) (we made our own annotation to invoke the Konform validation automatically on Controllers where we wanted this validation framework).

Even using Konform, we end up with the same thing - request objects whose fields are all nullable and then either using accessor methods with the `!!` syntax because we know by the same the object is accessed the validation has occurred, or transforming to a strongly typed object.

Comment: I mentioned allow field to be null, but that's not the best solution like I said. Using other validation frameworks will complicate the code and need to be combined with `springboot-web`.